# RdKafka Avro Consumer

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I need to read Avro messages in the C# RdKafka Client. In the console command i'm using this property:

--property schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081

How can i put this property in the configuration in the client?

```
    var config = new Config() { GroupId = "kafkaUser",
                                EnableAutoCommit = enableAutoCommit,
                                StatisticsInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60),
                                ["auto.offset.reset"] = "smallest",
                                ["?"] = "http://localhost:8081" };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Confluent.Kafka](https://github.com/ah-/rdkafka-dotnet/) is an alternative to the official [confluent-dotnet-kafka](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet), which was once considered as abandoned

They have now become the same project

---

In C# client, there are other projects like https://github.com/jakobz/schema-registry-dotnet - see in the test for usage with Avro library - and https://github.com/Judopay/Judo.Kafka/tree/master/src/Judo.Kafka, which use a portage of microsoft.Hadoop library to .net core and use https://github.com/Judopay/SchemaRegistryClient for schema registry client)

Comment: I found SchemaRegistry library in Nuget Manager, is it work with RdKafka or Confluent.Kafka? Or is there no way to get Avro by C# Client?

Comment: I don't know the schema registry nuget - there are multiple opensource library (schemaregistry, jacobz, judo.kafka) which provide some support, but I had some issues when testing them)

If you are ok to use a prerelease nuget from appveyor soure, I might get you one this we, but consider this as a work in progress, not official
Are you using .net framework or .net core? This will only works on .net 45+, .netcoreapp20 and netstandard20, not netcoreapp1.x or netstandard 1.x


One of the problem we will face is that avro library in C# are not complete

Comment: This info is outdated.